# Hero doesn't work when using Transition package in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I have two screens. There are Hero widgets on both of them and they work properly when I switch between them using basic Navigator function like this:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(PageRouteBuilder(pageBuilder: (context, animation, _) => Page2(index: widget.index));
```

However when I want to use [transition](https://pub.dev/packages/transition) package my Hero widgets don't work (it works like there are no Hero widgets).

```
        Navigator.of(context).push(Transition(child: Page2(index: widget.index), transitionEffect: TransitionEffect.RIGHT_TO_LEFT));
```

Could you help me find out why it doesn't work with this package.

Comment: Would you attach error log?

Comment: @KuKu no, there aren’t any errors, Hero widget just doesn’t work

Comment: Does it cause by same duration value? I think that because  the page transition duration and Hero duration is same, page transition is completed and Hero animation is also completed.

Comment: @KuKu could you please explain it more clearly. When I was using old transition the new screen was appearing and my widget (which has a Hero above it) was moving to the new position as it should. But now it is not moving like a hero widget, it is just appearing in the new screen like there is no hero widget.

Comment: I just wonder that transition pakcage's effect and Hero moving effect are done same time. But you means that Hero widget is not located destination place after screen loaded. hm....

Comment: Please share a more source to test that.

Comment: @KuKu I fixed the issue by using another package called [page_transition](https://pub.dev/packages/page_transition). It has all the same features and Hero is working properly with it. Anyway thanks for helping.

Comment: This question could use [repro]. Check out [ask] to improve this question